# Downloading a working - local version of a website without js/css version names

Tags: download, wget

Is there a way to wget local version of a website without its version names of js/css? What I used to get the site is below:

```
wget --mirror --page-requisites --convert-links --adjust-extension --compression=auto --reject-regex "/search|/rss" --no-if-modified-since --no-check-certificate --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" http://www.example.com
```

But it crawled the files with it's version names so my js file looks like this:

```
frontend.min.js@ver=2.5.11
```

Instead of

```
frontend.min.js
```

Also, source code has the same thing:

```
../jquery/frontend.min.js?ver=2.5.11
```

I would like to evade that and have it save without version names/info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing `--page-requisites` if you don't need things such as pictures or interactive elements. Removing this will cause wget to not download any CSS or JS files.